# How to save embeddig matrix (from a CSV) as tensorflow embedding checkpoint?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I have a csv file which has feature vectors of an embedding space (an M x N vector file) and I want to visualize it using tensorboard projector. I dont use tensorflow often and most examples I see online are form session graph built when a model in trained.

For my problem statement, I attempted to do the following which isn't right (error follows the code):

```
PATH = os.getcwd()

# path to the folder that we want to save the logs for Tensorboard
LOG_DIR = PATH + "/tf_logs/embedding" 

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

embed_var = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'text_embeddings.tsv'))
embedding_var = tf.Variable(embed_var.to_numpy())

saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver([embedding_var])
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  saver.save(sess, os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'model.ckpt'))


# Set up config
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embedding = config.embeddings.add()
embedding.tensor_name = "domain-embedding"

# the metadata find contains labels for each row of feature vector for embedding file
embedding.metadata_path = "../../domains.tsv"

summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR)
```

Error:

```
2021-09-14 00:46:01.157703: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-09-14 00:46:01.157731: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1835] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-09-14 00:46:01.158119: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:tensorflow:Saver is deprecated, please switch to tf.train.Checkpoint or tf.keras.Model.save_weights for training checkpoints. When executing eagerly variables do not necessarily have unique names, and so the variable.name-based lookups Saver performs are error-prone.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tsne-domain-descriptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    saver.save(sess, os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'model.ckpt'))
  File "/home/syadav/anaconda3/envs/clip3_6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1146, in save
    "`build()` should be called before save if defer_build==True")
RuntimeError: `build()` should be called before save if defer_build==True
```

I know people refrain from TF1 but I did TF1 a long time ago so was easier for me to write with sessions but I welcome suggestions and explinations in both versions (1 and 2).

Comment: Does this help https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_projector_plugin